# AS3 scale x and y using tween to give movieclip bounce effect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, tween

I am trying to give my "buttons" a bounce in effect using the tween class. I am also trying to make my code more efficent by using a function to handle this effect for all my buttons.

```
var MusicClip:MovieClip  = new music_mc();
var MoviesClip:MovieClip  = new movie_mc();
var GameClip:MovieClip  = new game_mc();

MusicClip.y = 63;
MusicClip.x = 577;
MoviesClip.y = 87;
MoviesClip.x = 401;
GameClip.y = 75;
GameClip.x = 151;

addChild(MusicClip);
addChild(MoviesClip);
addChild(GameClip);
```

This is where I am having a hard time. I thought I had to tween both the
scaleX and scaleY for all three MovieClips, but the button just appears on the 
stage and doesn't animate in. Also if I can put this code in a function so I 
don't have to write it for every button (and future buttons) that would be great.

```
var scaleTween:Tween=new Tween(MusicClip,"scaleX",Elastic.easeOut,0,1,1,true);
var scale2Tween:Tween=new Tween(MusicClip,"scaleY",Elastic.easeOut,0,1,1,true);
```

I am not getting any error but there is no bouncing in effect.

Comment: so, nothing happens at all? could you please post more code? and what `Tween` class do you use?

Comment: Where do you assign the animations to an event?  No errors of any sort implies that you are not actually taking action on the events coming from your buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign listeners to your MovieClips that will perform an action when you do something.  You can use a single event handler for all of your MovieClips:

```
MusicClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,bounceButton);
MusicClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,bounceButton);
MoviesClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,bounceButton);

function bounceButton(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var scaleTween:Tween=new Tween(event.target,"scaleX",Elastic.easeOut,0,1,1,true);
    var scale2Tween:Tween=new Tween(event.target,"scaleY",Elastic.easeOut,0,1,1,true);
}
```

Note that rather than specifying any one MovieClip as the tween target, you are using `event.target`, which will refer to the MovieClip you have rolled over.

On an unrelated note, it is good practise to start instance names with a lower case letter.  This helps to distinguish them from class names which by convention have uppercase letters to start each word:

```
var myVariable:MyClass;
```